# Spring security 4 annotation loging failure

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to make a Spring application with Spring security 4, hibernate, and annotations.
I have 2 roles; "admin" and "operario".

This is my spring security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        .antMatchers("reportes/*").access("hasrole('USUARIO')")
        .antMatchers("/operario/**").access("hasRole('OPERARIO')")
        .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
        .usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
@Controller
public class OperarioController {

    @Autowired
    private OperarioService operarioService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/operario/inicio", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView inicioOperario(){

        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("operario/inicio");

        //mock
        List<Proyecto> proyectos = operarioService.obtenerProyecto(new Operario());

        mav.addObject("proyectos",proyectos);

        return mav;
    }
}
```

These are the database roles:

[image]

If I log in with "operario", when I try to access to my application `"localhost:8081/mantenimiento/operario/inicio"` I get a access denied.
This is wrong because I have the role_operario with the user operario.

If I log in with the account admin, I can go to `"localhost:8081/mantenimiento/admin"`, I have a good log in.

I don't known what i'm doing wrong with the spring security configuration.

thanks for reading and if anyone need more information just ask i will upload it quickly as possible.

this is my CustomUserDetailsService

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userService.findBySso(ssoId);
    System.out.println("User : "+user);
    if(user==null){
        System.out.println("User not found");
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
    }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getSsoId(), user.getPassword(), 
             user.getState().equals("Active"), true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
}


private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for(UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfiles()){
        System.out.println("UserProfile : "+userProfile);
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userProfile.getType()));
    }
    System.out.print("authorities :"+authorities);
    return authorities;
}
```

}

I put the "ROLE_" before returning the authority.

Comment: is it `ROLE_OPERARIO` or `OPERARIO` what you have after you built your principal in the `customUserDetailsService`? the `hasRole()` method can result confusing, as it prepends the `ROLE_` to the specified parameter, returning a false if the authority doesn't include the `ROLE_`, if that is the case you could use `hasAuthority()` instead.

Comment: i just added the CustomUserDetailsService

Answer (score 0):

It was an empty space in the database field with a .trim() the problem  was solved, a noob error sry

Comment: those are quite annoying to find, indeed